# auto suggest/ auto complete in a textarea

Tags: jquery

I have a small requirement like . i need to fetch all record from table or store elements in key=>value pair. so that when a user types in the key . it should show the value part of it and if he presses enter button ,it should use it or else continue with typing.  I need to use jquery framework.

Is there any plugin already available for it . or how do i do it.

ex  : bp => blood pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this autosuggest pulg-in may help you to achieve your task : this not the thing you want but you have to write script so that it works as you want

[jQuery plugin: Autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)

[jQuery Autocomplete Plugin Demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/)